# Find entire $f$ from $|f|$

Tags: complex-analysis, absolute-value, entire-functions

$f$ is a Complex function.

Can we find entire function $f$ when we know the absolute value of $f$, $|f|$?

I want to know what entire function has absolute value as $$|f| = e^{(x^3-3xy^2)}$$

I do not think $f$ is unique... but can I find them all?

Comment: $f$ will be unique up to a constant of module $1$, because $\frac {f_1}{f_2}$ is bounded and (therefore) entire for any two candidates $f_1$, $f_2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Suppose that $g$ is an entire function such that $\operatorname{Re}g(x+yi)=x^3-3xy^2$. Then$$\left|e^{g(x+yi}\right|=e^{\operatorname{Re}g(x+yi)}=e^{x^3-3xy^2}.$$

Comment: What about the imaginary part?

Comment: In order to compute it, one uses the Cauchy-Riemann equations.

Comment: Where did it go though? because $\lvert z\rvert = \sqrt{\operatorname{Re}^2z+\operatorname{Im}^2z}$, right?

Comment: $|e^{x+yi}|=|e^xe^{yi}|=|e^x||e^{yi}|=e^x=e^{\operatorname{Re}(x+yi)}$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Observe that

$$\log|f|=\log\left(e^{x^3-3xy^2}\right)=\Re(z^3).$$

You can retrieve the imaginary part from the Cauchy-Riemann equations and you can expect some resemblance to $\Im(z^3)$.